# How to pass value of class in other class?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm losing myself in a glass of water. I'm doing a project where I want to manage different types of users: registered, visitor, official and administrator. Obviously, official and administrator are registered users.

So, I created 4 classes of which an abstract User.

- User (abstract)
- RegisteredUser extends User
- OfficerUser extends RegisteredUser
- UnregisteredUser extends User
- AdminUser extends User
- Document

The Document class that has attributes (date, type, etc.) is called in User (for site registration).

The Admin user can appoint OfficerUser users through a panel.

My question is this, how can I recall the Document class within OfficerUser? I basically have to move the RegisteredUser array to the OfficerUser array with the same Username.

Thanks, I am attaching the code of the various classes.

```
public class AdminUser extends User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AdminUser(){}

    public AdminUser(String username, String password, String email)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }


public class UnregisteredUser extends User 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static UnregisteredUser unregistered;

    private UnregisteredUser(){ }

    public static UnregisteredUser get()
    {
        if(unregistered == null)
        {
            unregistered = new UnregisteredUser();
        }
        return unregistered;
    }
}

public class Documento implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String type;
    protected String number;
    protected String sender;
    protected String date_sender;
    protected String date_limit;

    public Documento (String type, String number, String sender, String date_sender, String date_limit) {
        this.type = type;
        this.number  = number;
        this.sender = sender; 
        this.date_sender = date_sender;
        this.date_limit= date_limit;

    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getDate_sender() {
        return date_sender;
    }

    public void setDate_sender(String date_sender) {
        this.date_sender = date_sender;
    }

    public String getDate_limit() {
        return date_limit;
    }

    public void setDate_limit(String date_limit) {
        this.date_limit = date_limit;
    }


public class OfficerUser extends RegisteredUser implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public OfficerUser() {}

    protected Documento doc;

    public OfficerUser (RegisteredUser user)
    {
        this.username = user.username;
        this.password = user.password;
        this.email = user.email;
        this.name = user.name;
        this.surname = user.surname;
        this.fiscal_code = user.fiscal_code;
        this.telephone = user.telephone;
        this.doc = 

    }
```

This is the part of the database with MapDB and I'm working on eclipse with GWT.

```
public ArrayList<User> nominateOfficer( String userName){
    RegisteredUser normalOfficer = (RegisteredUser) userMap.get(userName);
    User officer = new OfficerUser(normalOfficer);
    userMap.replace(userName, normalOfficer, officer);
    this.db.commit();
    return getRegistered();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could model it in such a way that Office Users and Administrators are roles rather than users.

So roles are special in a way which specify what a user can do and you can attach different roles to different users without creating user types.

This way your modelling relationship is a lot flexible as you could add more roles to a user without creating more classes.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I wanted to use an abstract model pattern. That's why I used this class diagram.

Comment: For me it is sometimes easier to break down a problem into intrinsic properties that a object has vs something it can do or is capable of doing. I'd break down the problem and then decide what's the best pattern to use rather than 'IT HAS TO BE THIS PATTERN OR THE WORLD BURNS!'

Comment: Just asking, I don't see User as an abstract class in your code ?